# To extract text from square bracket java regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I extract the texts within the CardType:[ ..... ]

```
CardType:[ CashRebate=[true], Platinum=[true], CoBrandCard=[true]{CoBrandType:Holt Renfrew}, ChargeCard=[true], ConsumerCard=[true], Product Type Code:null ]
```

Initially i tried with following piece of code

```
pattern p = Pattern.compile("CardType:\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
```

m getting output as

```
CashRebate=[true
Platinum=[true
```

can any one help me out please

Thanks

Comment: Please define the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output to be:

`CashRebate=[true], Platinum=[true], CoBrandCard=[true]{CoBrandType:Holt Renfrew}, ChargeCard=[true], ConsumerCard=[true], Product Type Code:null`

Just make the regex non-lazy:

```
pattern p = Pattern.compile("CardType:\\[(.*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
```

This makes the regex match the last instance of `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pattern p = Pattern.compile("CardType:\\[\s(.*?)\s\\]");
```